# What is the difference between two Flink Redis sink dependencies with groupId `org.apache.bahir` and `org.apache.flink`?

Tags: java, maven, redis, apache-flink, apache-bahir

I am learning Flink. I try to add a Redis sink. In the [official Flink doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/overview/), it links to a [Apache Bahir doc](https://bahir.apache.org/docs/flink/current/flink-streaming-redis/), which is using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-redis_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

However, I found another `flink-connector-redis` at [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-redis_2.11/1.1.5):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-redis_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

As you see the `groupId` is different.

I found the info about Apache Bahir at their [website](https://bahir.apache.org/#home).

> Apache Bahir provides extensions to multiple distributed analytic
> platforms, extending their reach with a diversity of streaming
> connectors and SQL data sources.
>
> Currently, Bahir provides extensions for Apache Spark and Apache
> Flink.

What is the difference between these two dependencies? Which one is recommended to use first? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flink-connector-redis` was under `org.apache.flink` first. Then it is moved under `org.apache.bahir` and planned to maintain from there. It is the same codebase but bahir snapshots do have some improvements in both bug fixes and enhancements.